# How and when does Foundation's Locale data get updated?

Tags: ios, locale, foundation

My financial exchange app needed to be updated as Venezuela added a new currency in August. Below is the ISO currency information from the Swiss Assoc. for Standardization on Venezuela's new currency. The currency code is VES.

```
<CcyNtry>
<CtryNm>VENEZUELA (BOLIVARIAN REPUBLIC OF)</CtryNm>
<CcyNm>Bolívar Soberano</CcyNm>
<Ccy>VES</Ccy>
<CcyNbr>928</CcyNbr>
<CcyMnrUnts>2</CcyMnrUnts>
</CcyNtry>
```

But I'm still not seeing the currency code VES in Apple's Locale struct. This code appears correct for other currencies. I'm using Xcode 10.1.

```
let currencyCode = "VES"
let identifierList = Locale.availableIdentifiers.map { Locale(identifier: $0)}.filter { return currencyCode == $0.currencyCode }
print(identifierList)
```

Have I failed to do something on my end to see the currency? Is the code wrong? Do I wait for a new Xcode version? I'm trying to get a sense of how and when built-in data gets updated.

Comment: This is less of a programming question and more of a "when will Apple update iOS/macOS with the updated locale information" question.

Comment: So this is a matter of waiting months for an Xcode update as opposed to installing something? Because it has been so long, I was wondering if the lookup code is wrong.

Comment: It has nothing to do with Xcode. It's a matter of Apple adding support to iOS and macOS.

Comment: Ok. I thought I must be doing something wrong. Do you happen to know if there is a particular place to request these updates? I guess just general Apple support?

Comment: http://bugreport.apple.com

Comment: Ok. Very good. Thank-you matt. I have placed my first bug report.